# Get selected object from bound select dropdown with optgroup

Tags: angular

I am grouping some a schoolclass + subject model which then looks like this:

[image]

Everything is fine so far, except the selected test type like 'Presentation' is returned as current item as string, but I want the object behind so I can also get the id of that test type!

How can I do that?

With a common select **without** optgroup I had no problem with that requirement, but with the grouped select it does not work!

**Initialization**:

```
 let groupedTestTypes = Enumerable.from(responseTestTypes).GroupBy(g => g.schoolclassCode, g =>
                g, (key, g) => new TestTypePair(key, Enumerable.from(g).ToArray())).ToArray();
            this.testTypes = groupedTestTypes;
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentTestType">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let testType of testTypes" label="{{testType.key}}">
        <option *ngFor="let item of testType.testTypes">
            {{item.name}}
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**TestType.ts**

```
export default class TestType {

    constructor(obj)
    {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.schoolclassNumber = obj.schoolclassNumber;
        this.subjectName = obj.subjectName
        this.schoolclassCode = this.schoolclassNumber + " " + this.subjectName;
    }

    id: number;
    name: string;
    schoolclassNumber: string;
    subjectName: string;
    schoolclassCode: string;
}
```

**TestTypePair.ts**

```
import TestType from './testtype';
export default class TestTypePair {
    constructor( public key: string, public testTypes: TestType[]) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NgValue` directive on your select options:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentTestType">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let testType of testTypes" label="{{testType.key}}">
        <option *ngFor="let item of testType.testTypes" [ngValue]="item">
            {{item.name}}
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is the exact case `NgValue` directive is meant for - when you have object in displayed as items, you can use it to specify what value to return when you select something. (for example name, id or whole object)

Comment: darn... I just compared to my common select and yes I forgot the btw. [ngValue]="item", not [ngValue]="testType" ;-) Thanks though!

Comment: @Pascal Yeah, it's `item`, my bad. :-) Don't worry, small mistakes like that happens all the time to everyone. :-)

Comment: hey no biggi it happens to me too ;-)